# performing Authentication in a RESTful app

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I was looking at ways to perform authentication in application which primarily work out of RESTFUL APIs. I am specifically referring to MEAN stack apps. Here the backend (Node + express) and front-end (Angular) are completely decoupled and have no linkages whatsoever.

The way I am performing authentication is that 
1. When the user first logs in, the server includes userid in an encrypted form in x-access-token header of HTTP message. Then on all sub-sequent requests, the server will check the request headers for the token

```
 var token = (req.body && req.body.access_token) || parsed_url.access_token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
```

On the client side, I use angular interceptors to capture this header, decrypt it and then re-send it when making subsequent calls.

There is no use of cookies or sessions anywhere in this procedure (I believe this is how REST truly needs to be implemented)

This is all working for now.

But my question is, is this is the right way to do things. What are the disadvantages of using this over cookies ?

Comment: I use exactly the same approach and don't see any cons so far

Answer (score 0):

If user ID is easy to guess or enumerate (and you have to assume that the encryption method is  known -- we dislike "security by obscurity"), then clients can fake encrypted user ids. More over, if anyone obtains the user id (is your traffic https?), they can do the same.

You thus have to:

1. Append a "valid until" timestamp to the token returned by the server.
2. Hash the resulting "validity:userId" using a secret key on the server, and append the resulting hash to the token, making the token "validity:userId:hash(validity + user_id)".
3. On the server side, check that the hash matches (rehash "validity:userId" and compare to the 3rd part of the token).

If you do that, you can also send "userId" as plain, no need to encrypt.

Comment: ok.. so you are suggesting one should create a hash out of the user id and append it to the userID being sent in the x-access-token. This hash must also include some kind of timestamp so that the server can keep track of length of session. Further on the server-side, one should decrypt the hash, obtain the user-id from it and check it against the actual user-id sent. did i get this right ?

Comment: Not quite, but close. I am suggesting the server sends `x-access-token` that is equal to: `user_id` (unencrypted) + `:` + `validity_timestamp` + ':' + `hash(user_id + ':' + validity_timestamp)`. On the server, break the token into 3 parts. First check that `validity_timestamp` hasn't expired. If so, check that `hash(user_id + ':' + validity_timestamp)` eqauls to the 3rd part of the token.

Comment: so since only i know how to generate the hash.. i would be the only person able to match it over and over again, so the way this helps would be that if someone did try to spoof a user-id .. they would not be able to spoof the hash.. ok.. that's surely one way of doing it.. the advantage of this would be that I would not need to decypt stuff on client side.. am i right or are there other advantages to this ?

Comment: You're right. Plus any such token is time limited, so if stolen is only valid for a while.